# Eclipse Syntax Coloring : How to change the Query Parameter color with colon

Tags: java, eclipse

As we all know we can customize the color for different Java aspects in `Syxtax Coloring` option in Eclipse.

What I am trying is to find out some way by which we can change the color of the Query Parameter inside the native query string.

For example :

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * from Employee WHERE id = :empId;")
Employee fetchEmployeDetails(@Param("empId") empId)
```

I can change the method parameter color, but unable to change it inside the blue query string. I want to know is there any way out to change the color for this part inside the query string : `:empId`

As everything is in blue for a String, I find it difficult to recognize what are my query parameters that I am passing dynamically, as I have very long query and multiple inputs.

Comment: That is just a string as far as the syntax colouring is concerned. You can change the colour for all strings in the syntax colouring preferences. Also note that the string value can be any static final String so you could move it in to a string constant.

Comment: As greg-449 said, in Java it's just a String. But there might be an Eclipse plugin that provides coloring for that specific `@Query` annotation (Eclipse provides an extension point for that).